# linux install on single boot macbook pro 6,2

Tags: boot, macbook

novice here: i am trying to reasonable wipe anything remaining of this macbook for a clean linux install again.. while installing python/eclipse things got flaky and froze up and i had to shut down and restart.. downhill from there.. won't shutdown properly. won't boot.. so i'm ready for a new reformat of the drive and new install (i'm all backed up).. with that said. i am on a live usb and mounted the sda2 and ran the command 'efibootmgr' at the terminal.. what i got was:

- mint mint # sudo efibootmgr
- BootCurrent: 0000
- Timeout: 5 seconds
- BootOrder: 0000,0080
- Boot0000* ubuntu
- Boot0080* Mac OS X
- Boot0082*
- BootFFFF*

not sure what this means other than ubuntu is booting 'first'. i only use the linux os. so do i need/want to have the mac os in this boot process? unless i need the mac os for something i don't know about. just thinking this might be the problem with things getting corrupted on a regular basis. simply just trying to run linux on an old macbook pro. any help/thoughts appreciated. thank you.

update: i am logged in with a live usb and when doing a 'fdisk -l' command i find:

     `Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1               1        2047        1023+  ee  GPT
    /dev/sda2       609517568   625141759     7812096   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    /dev/sda3   *        2048   609517567   304757760   83  Linux`

but when i run gparted: it shows /dev/sda1 as linux-swap and /dev/sda2 as ext4. those are the only 2 partitions.

also on sda2 i get "...attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2 Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.."

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents from the following link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation

It contains official installation instructions for Ubuntu on Apple computers. Read carefully and follow the tutorial step by step in the "single boot" section. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have done this several times. Currently I am booting to a black screen. Nothing else.

Comment: those 'official' install instructions don't work. but these work perfectly. . http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/#fixing-efi